# Open Source Winforms applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, open-source

I'm looking for open source applications, built with winforms in C#. Specifically, i'm looking for applications using new and real world techniques. Like nerddinner and oxite for asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: GitExtensions is a large WinForms app and is open source: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is an excellent example IMO

Another one *was* [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html), but it's no longer open source, see comments.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to check it out!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, the source for SharpDevelop was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Paint.NET is [no longer open source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1693528/24874).

Answer (score 5):

Look to [codeplex](http://codeplex.com/), [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) and [Code Google](http://code.google.com/). There is lot of applications :)

Next resource is [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/).

---

Paint.Net is nice example.
[Here](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source%5Fcodes/paint.net.cfm) is source code.

Comment: I searched through the above hosting sites, it seems to me the real world winform projects are surprisingly not many, considering winform has been around for long time, and is the "standard" windows desktop framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, Paint.NET is [no longer open source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1693528/24874).

Answer (score 3):

NUnit is a good "real world" open source application...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit/