# Does Paint.Net still provide its source code

Tags: open-source, paint.net

Paint.Net used to provide a link to its source, but I can't find it (although if I recall the link was hard to find).  Does any one know if they no longer provide the source.  I'm only looking for it as a .Net application to learn coding practices and architecture from.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The source is no longer available.

See here:
http://blog.getpaint.net/2009/10/14/paintnet-v35-beta-3-build-3572-is-now-available/

And more info here:
[http://blog.getpaint.net/2007/12/04/freeware-authors-beware-of-“backspaceware”/](http://blog.getpaint.net/2007/12/04/freeware-authors-beware-of-%E2%80%9Cbackspaceware%E2%80%9D/)

Comment: Can't believe people actually were ripping the source code off like that  ... I guess I should have known this was happening from the warning on the install.

Comment: This is quite unfortunate. Unfortunately the only thing the original Author has done is take away something that was extremely useful for the community at large. In all reality it's still just as easy to decompile Paint.NET and replace all the Logo's, Title's and Names. And yet it's infinitely more difficult to contribute back to the project. The 'troll' won and we lost. It did not have to be this way.

Comment: I'm very late there, but @AndrewTFinnell -- I agree that it did not have to be this way.  I think in life, we have to be careful to not take reactive actions for a few rotten apples at the detriment of way more value added for way more people.  Shit happen.  Some people are bad.  Etc.  It is a risk, but most time a risk worth to take.  Like you said, someone that still want to do this can just hack the program a little and still achieve the same thing that user that pissed him off did.  Did the supposed "troll" or let's say "villain" won?  Or everyone lost?

Answer (score 29):

Paint.NET is no longer open source, but the last open source version was forked, and is available as [OpenPDN](https://github.com/rivy/OpenPDN) (forked from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openpdn/)).

Answer (score 13):

Although the Paint.Net source code is no longer available, there's a similar image editing program called [Pinta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinta_%28software%29) which has drawn inspiration from the former. It's written in C# (although uses the GTK GUI toolkit) so the architecture from a programming point of view maybe somewhat similar. Here's the [project page](http://pinta-project.com/), and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta).